# Making a delete.php file, code give me error

Tags: php

> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

the error is just on line 1, but my code only have

```
<?php
include 'db.php';

$id=(isset($_REQUEST['grants_id']) ? $_REQUEST['grants_id'] : '');

$query = "DELETE FROM grants WHERE grants_id=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die ( mysqli_error($link));
header("Location: ../user/view_grants.php");
?>
```

this is the code in db.php

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'rmc_myra');


$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($query)` give you?

Comment: check `var_dump($id);` and let us know what is coming. change `: ''` to `: 0`

Comment: Only query when you have an `id` set

Comment: Be careful that this request is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, even more because this is a `DELETE` request and that `$id` can come from any type of request parameter (use of `$_REQUEST`). See for prepared statements. Mandatory [bobby tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) link

Comment: it say Unknown column '$id' in 'where clause'. Does it mean it did not detect my grants_id?

Comment: @Arif  does your table have `grants_id` column?\

Comment: @Arif  you need to do code like this:- https://3v4l.org/KRTZC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. Why are you putting all the condition inside brackets.

```
$id=(isset($_REQUEST['grants_id']) ? $_REQUEST['grants_id'] : '');
```

replace this line from the below line.

```
    $id = (isset($_REQUEST['grants_id'])) ? $_REQUEST['grants_id'] : 0;
    if($id > 0){
      // your code
    }
```